Is the permutation test possible even when the randomization scheme is a restricted randomization?
Imagine an experimental setting where the participants are assigned randomly to some treatment groups. However, a form of restricted randomization is used (known by the experimenter).
After the experiment is finished, I could do a test where I use repeat the use of this restricted randomization, register a test statistic assuming no treatment effects to obtain a simulated distribution of this test statistic. After that I can obtain a p-value by looking at how extreme the test statistic is in the original data compared to the simulated data. My first question would be: Can I call this a randomization test?
Now imagine I do the same as described above, but I use a uniform/total randomization instead of the restricted randomization. My second and main question would be: Am I "allowed" to do this? Even if I know the assignment scheme does not come from this distribution, I can pretend that if it did: we would get a certain specific p-value that we can use to asses whether a treatment has an effect. I would say, but it does sound fishy.
Also, can I call this second procedure a permutation test?
